# How to set default matplotlib style?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When using matplotlib, I tend to use

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
```

quiet often. Is there an easy way to change the default style to ggplot (or any other style)? I looked into the 'matplotlibrc'-documentation but was unable to find an appropriate option.

Is there a better way then copying/linking the system-wide .mplstyle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, there is no such option (yet).

However, you can tell iPython to load the ggplot style at startup, by adding "plt.style.use('ggplot')" to  c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines in ipython_config.py.

Comment: How can I find which `ipython_config.py` is being used? In my profile, if I use `find`, there are 8 files with this name. In fact they are all in anaconda3/../jupyter folders, but I am not using jupyter, I am using spyder!

Answer (score 6):

You can change the settings file of matplotlib. According to the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file) :

> matplotlib uses matplotlibrc configuration files to customize all kinds of properties, which we call rc settings or rc parameters. You can control the defaults of almost every property in matplotlib: figure size and dpi, line width, color and style, axes, axis and grid properties, text and font properties and so on.

You can locate your matplotlibrc file with the following command:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()
```

Hence we can put ggplot settings at the end of the matplotlibrc file. You can easily find [ggplot style](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib/ggplot.mplstyle) (as well as [other styles](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/tree/master/lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib)) on official matplotlib repository.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer if you want the style to be used for all matplotlib renderings and not just iPython.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file (call it e.g. startup-01.py) in 
~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/

(substitute another profile name for profile_default as needed)

and put there any needed notebook (and interactive ipython) initialization statements, including

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

## other settings, e.g.
# plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10.0, 8.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`plt.style.use('default')` worked for me.

As I understand this, it tells matplotlib to switch back to its `default` *style mode*.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.